# Styling buttons using C++ Win32 Gdiplus

Tags: c++, windows, gui

This portion is for a button style. I set the style depending on if it is pressed or not. I was wondering if I could write this better or more efficient. Mainly the way I use `new`.

```
bool Draw::CustomButton(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT pDIS) {

using namespace Gdiplus;

// Control info
int ctlResID = pDIS->CtlID;            
Status lastCall = (Status)0;

// The bounding box of the button
Rect rect(0.0f,0.0f,pDIS->rcItem.right, pDIS->rcItem.bottom);

// Prepare the text
const int buffer_size_ = 16;
char textCharArray[buffer_size_];
GetWindowTextA(pDIS->hwndItem, textCharArray, buffer_size_);
std::string buttonText = std::string(textCharArray);

// Button state, down or up
bool button_down = false;
if (pDIS->itemState & ODS_SELECTED) button_down = true;


/* Pens, Brushes, Fonts, etc, depending on state *********/
// Center Align
StringFormat format;
format.SetLineAlignment(StringAlignmentCenter);
format.SetAlignment(StringAlignmentCenter);
format.SetFormatFlags(0);

/* This only works with pointers to removed redundent code and making it eaiser to update */
LinearGradientBrush* lgBrushBackgroundPtr = new LinearGradientBrush(  rect, Color(255, 0, 120, 165), Color(255, 0, 90, 190), LinearGradientModeVertical);  
int borderSize = 0;
static Pen* penBorderPtr = NULL;
static Font* fontPtr = NULL;
static SolidBrush* fontColorPtr = NULL;


// Button Down
if (button_down) { 
    borderSize = 4;
    penBorderPtr       = new Pen ( Color ( 125, 0, 0, 0 ), borderSize );
    fontPtr            = new Font ( L"Arial", 18, FontStyleRegular, UnitPixel );
    fontColorPtr       = new SolidBrush ( Color ( 255, 255, 255, 255 ) );
}
// Button Up
else {
    borderSize = 4;
    penBorderPtr       = new Pen ( Color ( 125, 20, 20, 20 ), borderSize );
    fontPtr            = new Font ( L"Arial", 20, FontStyleRegular, UnitPixel );
    fontColorPtr       = new SolidBrush ( Color ( 255, 255, 255, 255 ) );
}    

 // Draw
Graphics g (pDIS->hDC);
lastCall = g.FillRectangle(lgBrushBackgroundPtr, rect);          
lastCall = g.DrawRectangle(penBorderPtr, rect);


StringEx(&g, buttonText, fontPtr, rect, ALIGN_CENTER, ALIGN_CENTER, fontColorPtr);

// Clean
g.Flush();   
delete penBorderPtr;
delete fontPtr;
delete fontColorPtr;
delete lgBrushBackgroundPtr;

return true;

}
```

The main thing I am looking at is how I draw the button with `new/ delete`